# DRF - how to implement object based permission on queryset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I implemented DRF as per the document. At one point I figured out, once the user is authenticated, the user is allowed to fetch data of any user in the systems.

I have implemented filtering as per [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) document.

I read through the permission document and could not find a way to filter out queryset based on the owner. In my one of the views, I am checking if the owner is same as the user who requested.

My question is, Do I have to do the same in all viewsets? or There is a general way where I can check this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if it is the best way, but I do it by overriding get_queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = YOUR_MODEL.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
    return queryset
```

Doing it, using permisson class

```
class IsInUserHierarchy(permissons.BasePermission):
     def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(isinstance(request.user, UserClassHierarchy))
```

Some explanations. `IsInUserHierarchy` class is very similar to `IsAdminUser`. It checks, if request.user is in the required class (import `UserClassHierarchy` from models), using simple python isinstance() method

Comment: Yes, this works. But I am looking for general way of doing it.

Comment: @KishorPawar - what do you mean saying "general way". You want to have some `Permisson class`?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I have a user hierarchy. Like parent and child user. I want to allow any user to retrieve the data owned by any user in the same hierarchy.

Comment: Have you thought about creating permisson class, where `has_permission` function `return bool(isinstance(request.user, Child_User_Class))`?

Comment: I tried doing something that @Dalvtor said in his answer below. How do I access `Child_User_Class` in `has_permission`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188749/discussion-between-kishor-pawar-and-headmaster).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a permissions file, and add something like this:

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

Then, in your ViewSet, use this permission class:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
```

Now, just import your permissions file anywhere you want to use this logic and you don't have to duplicate any code

Comment: This only works when you have a single object to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for anyone curious, you can still create follow the general procedure as outlined by Dalvtor and Django/DRF docs.

Your viewset makes a call to check the object through:

```
self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
```

With your custom permission, you need to check if it is iterable and iterate and check each object in the queryset:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from collections.abc import Iterable

class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # For Get Queryset (List)
        if isinstance(obj, Iterable):
            for o in obj:
                if o.user != request.user:
                    return False
        # For Get Object (Single)
        elif obj != request.user:
            return False
    return True
```